# Printing all files in shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

The program `txt.py` prints that takes in a directory as a command line parameter and prints all the files of a particular extension

```
def printAll(path):
        for txtFile in glob.glob(path):
        print txtFile

printAll(sys.argv[1])
```

In the command line I type in `python txt.py /home/Documents/*.txt`

It prints only the first `txt` file.
How do I print all `txt` files in that directory given we pass the directory from command line?

Answer (score 2):

At the command line the `*` is a shell wildcard, your shell expands it and passes a list of files to the script, e.g.

```
python txt.py "/home/Documents/1.txt" "/home/Documents/2.txt" "/home/Documents/3.txt"
```

You only look at the first argument, so only print one file.

You need to escape the * in your shell so it gets through to Python as a single argument with an asterisk. In bash shell, maybe:

```
python txt.py "/home/Documents/\*.txt"
```

**Edit**: As an alternative you could just take the directory path on the command line, and add the `*.txt` part in your program, e.g.

```
def printAll(path):
    path = path + "/*.txt"
    for txtFile in glob.glob(path):
        print txtFile

printAll(sys.argv[1])

call it with:
$ python txt.py "/home/Documents"
```

**Edit 2**: How about passing an example file in the path and the script can find files with the same file extension as that? It doesn't even have to exist. That sounds fun:

```
import os, sys

def printAll(path, fileext):
    query = os.path.join(path, '*.' + fileext)

    for someFile in glob.glob(query):
        print someFile

printAll(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

call it with
$ python txt.py /home/Documents txt
```

(os.path.join is a utility that adds / if it's needed)

Or how about passing an example file in the path and the script can find files with the same file extension as that? It doesn't even have to exist. That sounds fun:

```
import os, sys

def printAll(path):
    searchdir, filename = os.path.split(path)
    tmp, fileext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    path = os.path.join(searchdir, '*'.fileext)

    for someFile in glob.glob(path):
        print someFile

printAll(sys.argv[1])

call it with:
$ python txt.py "/home/Documents/example.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you tell me what changes I have to do in my code to prevent use of escape characters in shell

Comment: @ManabChetia I've updated my answer with an alternative - just take the directory name as a parameter to the script, and add the wildcard glob in your script.

Comment: There is no way for your program to make the shell not expand arguments before it runs. A simple workaround would be to just pass the directory name, if that's really what you want. A more versatile solution is to just process all the files you pass in, and use the shell's facilities such as wildcard expansion when they are useful.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: I want to find all files with a particular extension specified in the shell

Comment: @ManabChetia I've added an Edit 2 taking two parameters, one for the extension.

Comment: I am using this program to count the number of lines in a file. So if an user specifies `python txt.py /home/Documents/hello.txt`. It should display the total number of lines in `hello.txt` and if an user types in `python txt.py /home/Documents/*.txt`, it should display total number of lines for every `.txt` file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to how the shell works, you are actually passing in the entire list of files, but only using the first one.  This is because the shell will expand the `*` character and then as a result, all `*.txt` files are passed to your script.

If you simply do this in your script:

```
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(i)
```

You will see the list your program is supposed to print. To avoid this, you have a few options:

1. Quote your argument `"/home/Documents/*.txt"`
2. Pass only the extension part, `python txt.py /home/Documents/.txt`, and in your script:

   ```
   def print_all(path):
       path = path[:path.rfind('/')+1]+'*'+path[path.rfind('/')+1:]
       for i in glob.glob(path):
           print(i)
   ```
3. Pass *two* arguments, the path, and then the extension `python txt.py /home/Documents/ .txt` and then join them together:

   ```
   print_all(sys.argv[1]+'*'+sys.argv[2])
   ```